# Can Someone help me to find a dataset on the below requirement?

Tags: dataset, dummy-data

I am currently trying to find a data set which is repeating itself day by day. as an example, lets say there is a 50,000 of loans in a particular bank. The data should be repeated it self day by day. That means, in January 1st, the record count need to be 50K. on jan 2, the record count need to be 50,000 with daily updated records. Like wise.

So if there are 10 days, all the records count need to be 500,000 + New loans.

Hope you re now having a idea on the requirement. Can anyone help me to find such a data set?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When I thought of a dataset that is constantly being added to it, COVID came to my mind. There is a dataset like this: [COVID-19 Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/imdevskp/corona-virus-report?select=day_wise.csv), which shows that the number of cases is increasing every day. I don't know if it's exactly what you want, but maybe it will help.

(See **#Confirmed** in `day_wise.csv`)

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. this works well. Do you have any other files like this?

Comment: Do you have any specific areas to work on? I mean, on which subject do you want to find data sets, is it important?